# Calculating Cumulative Average every x successive rows in Excel( not to be confused with Average every x rows gap interval)

Tags: excel, pandas

[image]

I want to calculate cumulative average every 3 rows from the value field. Above figure shows the Column cumulative average which is expected output. Tried offset method but it gives the average after every 3 rows gap interval and not the cumulative average every 3 continuous rows.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what do you mean by cumulative sum every 3 rows? at least with a formula

Comment: Please provide an input dataframe (with code) and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly wrote Cumulative sum instead of Cumulative average every x succesive rows. Hope, it clarifies the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with `mean` and then [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
N = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [6,9,15,3,27,33]})
df['Cum_sum'] = df['Value'].rolling(N).mean().shift(-N+1)

print (df)
   Value  Cum_sum
0      6     10.0
1      9      9.0
2     15     15.0
3      3     21.0
4     27      NaN
5     33      NaN
```